# Word wrap text read from a file in text area

Tags: java, swing, text, jtextarea, text-parsing

How do I word wrap text in text area which is being read from a file? I.E. If the file reader detects a .(semicolon) it should automatically wrap or break the line.

For example I have:

```
Name address gender;
A.          B.           C.        
D.          E.            F.
```

So as soon as the reader reaches C. It should break and print D. from the next line

Comment: Your question is not clear.
No Code ?
Do you want it in JQuery or Java?

Comment: @BASEER HAIDER  i want it in java

Comment: fetch All the data from file then replace semi colon with \n (new line)

Comment: Can you please elaborate with a small piece of code please.

Comment: and setLineWrap(true)